# Rotating clears selected tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, android-app

Changing the orientation of your device within the tag selection view while asking a question removes all selected tags and clears the textbox.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Ask a question (does not happen when editing)
2. Edit tags
3. Enter some text in the box
4. Select a tag from the suggestion list
5. Repeat the previous two steps as many times as you care to
6. Rotate the device (source / target orientation doesn't matter, just
   need to change it)
7. All selected tags and text typed in the textbox are gone and must be
   re-entered

I've reproduced this using version 1.0.63 of the SE app on two devices:

- HTC One E8 m2ss (the Hong Kong version) rooted and running stock
  5.0.2
- ATT Galaxy S3 i747, rooted and sim unlocked, running Slimkat
  4.4.2.build.4.1.official ROM on Android 4.4.2

Comment: Can you confirm this has been fixed? Since there was never any 1.0.86 version, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.86.

Because of the way the app manages the tag picker fragment, on an orientation change the fragment gets repopulated from the ask question form.  Since there's no way to cancel tag changes from the picker, I'm just committing them instantly back to the form so that they'll be saved for orientation changes.