# Wrong name for a open-source project

Tags: bug, android-app

The name of the last one should be NOT "Butterknife".
Very minor issue, I know ... ;)

[image: Highlighted screenshot]

- App version: 1.0.85
- Device manufacturer: Xiaomi
- Device model: Redmi Note 3
- OS version: 5.1.1 (V7.3.6.0.LHOMIDD)

Comment: @ShadowWizard you are correct. i am closing it. thnx

Comment: Sure thing, too bad SE pretty much stopped developing the android app. (So this might never be fixed. The last time a bug was fixed was [nearly three months ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259633/rotating-clears-selected-tags), by someone who is not even android developer, but iOS developer.)